# Scrollable layout

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make such layout? Header should not scrolls and should be always visible.

[image]

The matter is Android throws an error when I try to put `ScrollView` into `LinearLayout`.

Markup:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              style="@style/baseLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/app_header" />
    <ScrollView
        style="@style/fillParent">
        <!-- elements here -->
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme">
    </style>

    <style name="fillParent">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="fullWidth">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
    <style name="wrapContent">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="baseLayout" parent="fillParent">
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_bg</item>
    </style>

    <style name="app_header" parent="fullWidth">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_bg</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me, could you post your code and let us see what you might be doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TITLE BAR"/>
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Solution**

The problem was that Ninja had more than 1 direct child in the `ScrollView`.

Comment: I am taking a look now. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `LinearLayout style="@style/app_header" />` Right now it seems like it is empty and not needed. You could try putting a `TextView` there instead and see what happens. You can change the background of `TextView`.

Comment: **That would be a problem, yes.** `ScrollView` only accepts one direct child. Also, appserv just mentioned this issue while you were making this comment. And R.daneel.olivaw mentioned in a comment to his answer.

Comment: The fact is I've found a problem only after your question "Can you give us the exact error you are getting?" :)

Comment: lol, i do that too. I have a few questions on SO where i have asked the question on here, then went back to look at the error a little deeper and then found the problem and posted my own answer. Taking a step back and typing up the problem usually helps me find my issues too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not normal if there is an error if you put a Linear layout in side a Scroll view.
Please try the below snippet in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TITLE BAR"/>

  <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        .
        .
      </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: DotNET Ninja said they were trying to put a `ScrollView` inside a `LinearLayout` not the other way around. Also, did you just copy what i did? lol

Comment: What he means is that in your case we will have to do that and also have a linear layout inside the scroll view, as in android scrollview can have only 1 child. So all the scrollable content will be inside the inner linear layout.

Comment: Yes, but just the <TextView> tag, I am sorry if it offended you.

Answer (score 1):

In your markup:

```
 ....  
 <ScrollView
      style="@style/fillParent">
       <!-- elements here -->
 </ScrollView>
 ...
```

"elements here" - If more than one then you will get an error, because ScrollView can host only one direct child (for example layout).